# What does it mean for a class to be composed of another class?

Tags: class, oop

What does it mean for a class to be composed of another class? 
For example:
Location class will be composed of several Set classes (two for each location).

Does it mean in the constructor definition, the Location will consist of 2 set objects?

Comment: It means they (several Set classes) will be members (properties, however you choose to name it..) of the Location class

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you quote does not necessarily make any assumptions regarding the constructor. It does make assumptions regarding the fields contained in the `Location` class.

It means that if class `A` is composed of two other classes `B` and `C`, then it will contain at least two fields of `B` and `C` type.

class `A` might look something like this (example in c#):

```
class A
{
    B b;
    C c;
}
```

It *may* also have a constructor such as:

```
public A(B b, C c)
{
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}
```